# Gnuradio loopback flowgraph is not working

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I found the below uhd_two_tone_loopback example (which is one of the gnuradio provided examples) and I am trying to run it, it runs but I can't receive signal.

**EDIT:**

I mean when I run the program I cannot hear the audio tone at all. If I connect an audio sink to the TX side I hear the audio. But when the audio sink is connected to the output port of the USRP source I can't hear the audio tone.

So, I have the b200 mini usrp and I am connecting the TX to the RX using an FW-10+ 10 dB attenuator.

What could be the problem that I can't get the loop working? Thanks.

Flowgraph:

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific — there are in general many different ways for things _not_ to work. When you say "can't receive signal", what _do_ you observe? What do you hear, and what do you see in the frequency sink? [Edit] your question to describe these observations.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO, Thanks Kevin. Thread is updated.

Comment: @Hadad more own debugging! What's the amplitude of the received signal? Do you see the sine in the spectrum display, as you'd expect? Why are you using a sampling rate that is at the very lowest border of what the USRP can do? How are you making sure sampling rates in this system match (hint: they don't, and you should be getting a lot of errors after a short time).